# filtering a data frame using a comparison between three columns of that data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a  dataframe that contains 1 million rows.
I tried to replicate the dataframe as simple as possible.
Below is the simple data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Match'] = ['A Vs B','A Vs B','A Vs B','A Vs B','A Vs B','C Vs D','C Vs D','C Vs D','C Vs D','C Vs D','C Vs D']
df ['Hwin'] = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
df ['Awin'] = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1]
df ['Draw'] = [0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0]
```

My actual data frame contains 30 over columns.
What I wanted to do as follow:
I want to keep only a row for each match where sum of one of the columns from **HWin** **Draw** **Awin** is greater than the rest two columns.
My expected output is as follow:

[image]

How can I do this?
Your advice is much appreciated.
Thanks,

Zep.

Comment: For the match C Vs D, Hwin is same as sum of Awin and Draw, not greater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC need `groupby` + `transform`, then we do row `max` and `idxmax`

```
s=df.groupby(df.columns.tolist())[['Hwin','Awin','Draw']].transform('sum')
df.loc[s.max(1).groupby(df.Match).idxmax()]
    Match  Hwin  Awin  Draw
0  A Vs B     1     0     0
5  C Vs D     0     1     0
```

Comment: It is not drop duplicates. It will drop all duplicates without looking at the comparison

Comment: Thanks, I should be the one who has to thank to you.

Comment: I will apply it t my df. Thanks